# Trouble in Automator's Shell Script after OS X 10.9 Mavericks upgrade

Tags: macos, terminal, automator, script, command-line

I've got a problem. I use from lot of time an Automator's shell script:

```
cat >> ~/Dropbox/ClipBoard/Appunti\ Mac\ del\ $(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).txt
```

It ever worked but, after Mavericks upgrade, it return an error while running: "ambiguous redirect (1)". Trouble should be depending from date's code, because using

```
cat >> ~/Dropbox/ClipBoard/Appunti\ Test.txt
```

it runs correctly. I tried modifying code or adding some quotes, for example

```
cat >> ~/Dropbox/ClipBoard/Appunti\ Mac\ del\ $ (date “%Y-%m-%d”).txt
```

but the trouble persists. How can I correct it?

Comment: If you paste the command from Automator directly into Terminal, does it work?

Comment: no, same trouble...

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462385/getting-an-ambiguous-redirect-error help?

Comment: I made some tests but it didn't solved...

Comment: Possibly related to the `date` command in Mavericks: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107839/parsing-dates-in-mavericks

Comment: yes, probably that's the trouble but I can't find a way to modify code to make it works...

Comment: What does `~/Dropbox/ClipBoard/Appunti\ Mac\ del\ $(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).txt` print in Terminal?

Comment: "No such file or directory", it can't exist!

Answer (score 1):

I think you were close and that the following should work:

```
cat >> ~/Dropbox/ClipBoard/Appunti\ Mac\ del\ $ (date "+%Y-%m-%d").txt
```

You had smart quotes in your sample and that won't work and you left out the plus in the quoted format string which you had included in your original.

Comment: no, it doesn't work..