# System hotkey to execute cmus-remote?

Tags: terminal, automator

I am a huge fan of the terminal-based music player [cmus](https://cmus.github.io/). It does everything I want from a music player and nothing I don't. I want to use it instead of iTunes on my Macbook. I installed it via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and it's working great, except for one thing...

I'm trying to set up a system hotkey to play/pause cmus even if it's not focused. cmus provides a command-line program to help you do this.

```
cmus-remote --pause
```

Running that from anywhere will connect to the running cmus instance via a socket and issue the play/pause command.

So I'm trying to set up a system hotkey to run that command and play/pause cmus. As [suggested in another answer](https://superuser.com/a/239235), I've tried creating an Automator service workflow that runs the script. So hotkey starts the Automator service which runs the shell script which runs `cmus-remote`.

[image: This workflow works perfectly in the GUI, but fails when run as a service]

Now here's the real problem:

This Automator workflow works perfectly when I run it from the Automator edit interface, but it always fails when I try to run it as a service. The error message contains no useful information, just "The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error."

I've attempted to put some debugging output into my script:

```
echo "AUTOMATION STARTED" >> ~/automation.txt
/usr/local/bin/cmus-remote --pause 2>&1 >> ~/automation.txt
```

When I read that file, all I see is:

```
AUTOMATION STARTED
```

Clearly the workflow is starting and running, and it's the `cmus-remote` command itself that is failing.

So...

1. Why this would `cmus-remote` work inside the Automator GUI, but die mysteriously outside of it?
2. Is there anyway to get more failure info out of cmus?
3. Are there open-source alternatives to Automator for binding system hotkeys to simple shell commands?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a security setting in Mavericks (and possibly Mountain Lion) that causes Automator not to allow system control. See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107895/trouble-in-automators-shell-script-after-os-x-10-9-mavericks-upgrade)

Open your Console and watch the logs when you run the service. In my case, it crashes when I try to run a shell script.

I tried adding Automator to the Security and Privacy preferences, but it did not solve the issue.

As a work around, you may have to use applescript to create and app, tie that to a service, and add the app to the Privacy tab of your Security and Privacy preference pane.